# Pages don't show up correctly in glossary (LaTeX)

Tags: latex, glossary

I'm try to make a simple glossary in my thesis.

That's a compilable sample

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{Tree}{
    name={Tree},
    description={Acyclic graph}
}
\newglossaryentry{Kn}{
    name={Complete graph},
    description={Graph that has all possible edges}
}


\begin{document}
    This is a \gls{Tree}
    \newpage
    
    This is a \gls{Kn}
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[title=Definitions]
\end{document}
```

In this sample, Complete graph appears in page 2, but in glossary everything is signed at page 1).

Am I referring to glossary's terms in a wrong way? The term is linked correctly to its glossary's entry.

Comment: You should ask this question in the [tex exchange forum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Flora Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sure! I'm adding it above

Comment: I do get page 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/aluWP.png Did you compile often enough? When did you run `makeglossaries`? Can you show your .log file of the mwe from your question?

Comment: Okay, now I get the same, but why tree is signed at both page 1 and 2? Shouldn't it only appear at page 1?